# Codeigniter multiple image upload with different field names

Tags: php, codeigniter, image-uploading

I tried to upload multiple image form using codeigniter here the view code

```
        echo form_open_multipart('banner/upload');
        //name
        echo form_input('name'); 

        //image1:
        $data= array(
                'name'=>'userfile',
                'value'=>'$userfile'
                    );
        echo form_upload($data);

        //image2:
        $data= array(
                'name'=>'userfile',
                'value'=>'$userfile'
                    );
        echo form_upload($data);

        //image3:
        $data= array(
                'name'=>'userfile',
                'value'=>'$userfile'
                    );
        echo form_upload($data);

        echo form_submit('upload','upload');
```

How to get three image file form post and how to validate the image

Comment: possible duplicate of  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19216067/i-have-a-working-multiple-upload-document-and-image-codeigniter

Answer (score 0):

aPlease refer to the below link: an additional library for multiple uploads in codeigniter.

https://github.com/stvnthomas/CodeIgniter-Multi-Upload